# Making a pill capsule filled with powder

Tags: modeling, texturing

I'm trying to create a realistic capsule that has a translucent shell and a powder interior (see image). Ideally, I'd be able to change the color of the powder interior easily. Can't seem to figure out how to get it looking realistic. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Consider using particles on the surface of a smaller interior capsule.  Use a group of particles with different colors.  You can have many different groups with different colors. Since you cannot see the inner powder clearly ... you may also consider a texture .. free textures exist on the internet.  Please research particles and textures here on BSE. ⚛

Comment: Please show your work so we can see your progress.

Answer (score 3):

Transparency is very difficult to get right, especially when there's something inside of the transparent object. https://blend-exchange.com/b/6V8odJJx Here is a link to my own recreation of your image. I used a Voronoi texture that's run through a colour ramp to get the right look of the inside of the pill. Doesn't need to be too detailed unless you zoom really close to the object. Then I duplicated the shape in object mode and extruded it to have a bit of thickness. I then added a new material and changed the transmission, alpha, roughness, and specular settings until I got something that looked decent. Make sure to change the IOR as well, it's automatically set to glass.

Here's an example of my attempt, it's by no means perfect but its a good jumping off point.

[image]

Comment: Want to include a rendered image so visitors don't have to download and render the file to get an impression?

Comment: Oh yeah good idea

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm playing around with it now and getting some fairly decent results. Would love to hear if anyone knows how to get the interior to feel more like a powder than a sand - but this is a good jumping off point as you say, thanks again!

Comment: Try messing with the roughness, sand is almost glass so perhaps making it darker and less shiny might help.

Answer (score 0):

After finding more references to powder-filled pills, I came up to the following result:

[image: Powder-filled pill with cracked soil texture]

Material nodes:

[image: Powder-filled pill with cracked soil texture node setup]

The normal map I used for this: https://quixel.com/assets/vl3kdazg

The color can be changed with a *Hue Saturation Value* node.